# Why is this merge sort implementation not giving the correct answer?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have 2 merge sort implementation in Python that looks the same but I have no idea why 1 of them isn't working.

```
def merge(left, right): 
    result = []
    i,j = 0,0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    while (i < len(left)):
        result.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    while (j < len(right)):
        result.append(right[j])
        j += 1
    return result

def merge_sort(L):
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = len(L)//2
        left = merge_sort(L[:middle])
        right = merge_sort(L[middle:])
        return merge(left, right)
```

Running `merge_sort([1,3,5,2,4,6])` gives `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` which is the correct answer.

However

```
def merge1(X,Y):
    result = []
    n = len(X)
    m = len(Y)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < n and j < m:
        if X[i] < Y[j]:
            result.append(X[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(Y[j])
            j += 1
    while (i < n):
        result.append(X[i])
        i += 1
    while (j < n):
        result.append(Y[j])
        j += 1
    return result


def merge_sort1(L):
    if len(L)  <2 :
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = len(L) // 2
        X = merge_sort1(L[:middle])
        Y = merge_sort1(L[middle:])
        return merge1(X,Y)
```

running `merge_sort1([1,3,5,2,4,6])` gives a strange answer `[1, 2, 3, 4]` which is wrong.

But I have no idea why the 2nd attempt gives an incorrect answer when it looks the same with the 1st attempt.
What is the problem and why did this happen?

Comment: you have `while i < n` (correct) and then `while j < n` (incorrect).  Second one should be `while j <m`

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `while (j < n):` instead of `while (j < m):`